# Is there any UUID and characteristic for receiving temperature values from BLE?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am designing a system to obtain temperature values of multiple sensors connected to my device using BLE.

I want to receive the values on an Android application using BLE module HM 10.

Please let me know what uuid and characteristic i should select.

Comment: [GATT services List](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services). You may be interested in [Health Thermometer](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.health_thermometer.xml)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a health thermometer you could use the service 0x1809.

But if you've got a couple sensors in your application the best thing you could do is build your own custom servive with your own 128 Bit UUID. Then you could build some characteristics for that service that fit best for your application.

Have a look at the [UUID Generator](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/)

Comment: Okay, but if i say i want to make BLEterminal like app just recieve the data from TX,RX as it is. Then what should be my approach.

Comment: Build your own custom service!

Comment: Okay how should i go for it.

Comment: Do you know of any github link where i can get the code for same?

Comment: Do you know of any github link where i can get the code for same?